# Pusher: Swift (iOS) publisher/server to Raspberry Python subsriber/client

Tags: python, ios, swift, raspberry-pi, pusher

In Pusher, is there a way to setup Python (Raspberry Pi) as the client and iOS (Swift) as the server?

This is the client/server setup page:
[Setting up a channel in pusher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUOfh.png).

The reason I am asking is because I followed the photo-feed tutorial in which a Raspberry Pi sends images to an iOS App: https://pusher.com/tutorials/photo-feed-swift-raspberrypi/.
I setup ngrok as the server on the Pi.

Now I would like to make an iOS app that sends command data to the Raspberry 
to turn a stepper motor.

Can this be done with the current setup from the photo-feed? Are channels bi-directional that I can send/receive from both ends or do I need two channels: one to send and one to receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pusher Channels are bidirectional (or omnidirectional). You can trigger events on a channel and all active subscribed clients should receive the event.

The tutorial mentioned doesn't show a subscription on the Raspberry Pi. You'll need to add that functionality. You may be able to use [Pysher](https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/Pysher) to subscribe to the channel and listen to incoming events that your mobile would send.

If you do this then you may wish to use [client events](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#trigger-events) to send events between both devices over the same channel subscription.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't used `Pysher` myself. I don't know whether it would work on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: This might help you in Pusher event debugger... https://twitter.com/FirecampHQ/status/1101028779311460353